# Java Spring Boot, probelm to save into PostgreSQL a map of two custom object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

i'm developing a management software for resturant (it's an university project). This is the situation: i have an object Ordination - Ordinazione - (I'm from Italy, so in the example all this name will be in italian). I'm explainig the entire problem first and then i will show you all the interested code. An ordination, in my logic, is composed by an object called InfoOrdine - information about the ordination -. Because when a waiter will note that, he had to consider the number of plate and the state of preparation for each of them.
In terms of logic, in the class Ordination i have something that for each plate associate ad information about all of this plate.
I have used a map for the implementation (Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infopiatto) and used the @OneToMany tag, because one ordination instance can have multiple record of piatto-information.
But when i save this in PostgreSQL through JPARepository, something strage happen. The table ordination with the attribute id_ordinazione, id_tavolo ed evasa is saved correctly. In the other side, the table info_ordine is "half-saved". I'm will show you the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkwFn.png)

id_ordinazion and id_piatto aren't saved and i don't know why. This two attributes are really importat because through them i can join the table with Ordinazione and obtain all the information that I want. Even more weird (for me obviuosly, i know that for someone else is easy to resolve this) is the fact that a new column is created autunomly (info_piatto_key) and act the role of id_piatto.
I'm showing you the class:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.springone3.demo.Controller.PiattoController;
import com.springone3.demo.MyCustomInfoPiattoDeserializer;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Entity
@Table
public class Ordinazione {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "ordinazione_sequence",
            sequenceName = "ordinazione_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "ordinazione_sequence"
    )
    private Long idOrdinazione;

    private String idTavolo;

    // L'opzione CacadeType.ALL assicura che tutte le operazioni di persistenza (inserimento, aggiornamento, cancellazione) eseguite sull'oggetto Ordinazione si riflettano anche sugli oggetti
    // InfoOrdine associati. L'opzione orphanRemoval = true permette di rimuovere automaticamente gli oggetti InfoOrdine orfani quando vengono rimossi dalla mappa 'infoOrdini'

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ordinazione",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto;

    private boolean evasa = false;
   

    public Ordinazione(Long idOrdinazione, String idTavolo) {
        this.idOrdinazione = idOrdinazione;
        this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
        this.infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
    }

  
    public Ordinazione() {
    }


    // getter and settet
  

    /*

    public void aggiungiPiatto(Piatto piatto, Integer quantity) {
        InfoOrdine info = new InfoOrdine(quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE);
        infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }

     */

    public void aggiungiPiatto(Piatto piatto, Integer quantity) {
        InfoOrdine info = new InfoOrdine(quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE, this);
        infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idOrdinazione=" + idOrdinazione +
                ", idTavolo='" + idTavolo + '\'' +
                ", infoPiatto=" + infoPiatto.toString() +
                ", evasa=" + evasa +
                '}';
    }



}
```

private idOrdinazione - the ID of the table/class - ;
private String idTavolo - an identifier for specify the table (in sense of resturant and not relational database).
private boolean evasa - the customer has received his food? -
Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto.

The last one is the critical part. In fact, i have two custom object type for key - value of the map.
The first one, is refered to plate of food. The class is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Piatto {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "piatto_sequence",
            sequenceName = "piatto_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "piatto_sequence"
    )

    private Long idPiatto;


    private String nome;

    private String descrizione;

    private String allergeni;



    //@JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "id_categoria"
          // nullable = false
           // referencedColumnName = "id_categoria"
    )
    private Categoria categoria;
    private String costo;

    public Piatto(Long idPiatto, Categoria categoria, String nome, String descrizione, String allergeni, String costo) {
        this.idPiatto = idPiatto;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.allergeni = allergeni;
        this.costo = costo;
    }

    public Piatto(Long idPiatto, String nome, String descrizione, String allergeni, String costo) {
        this.idPiatto = idPiatto;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.allergeni = allergeni;
        this.costo = costo;
    }


    public Piatto(){}



   // getter and setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[idPiatto:'" + idPiatto + '\'' +
                ", nome:'" + nome + '\'' +
                ", descrizione:'" + descrizione + '\'' +
                ", allergeni:'" + allergeni + '\'' +
                ", categoria:'" + categoria + '\'' +
                ", costo:'" + costo  + '\'' + "]";
    }

}
```

The second is referred to information about the ordination; for example two plate of appetizers, one of main course, etc with the state of preparations.
The class is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class InfoOrdine {

    @Id

    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "info_ordine_sequence",
            sequenceName = "info_ordine_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "info_ordine_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

//    @EmbeddedId
//    private InfoOrdineId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    // @MapsId("idOrdinazione")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ordinazione")
    private Ordinazione ordinazione;

    @OneToOne
    // @MapsId("idPiatto")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_piatto")
    private Piatto piatto;
    private int quantity;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine stato;

    /*

    public InfoOrdine(int quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine stato) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.stato = stato;
    }

     */

    public InfoOrdine(int quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine stato, Ordinazione ordinazione) {
        this.ordinazione = ordinazione;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.stato = stato;
    }

    public InfoOrdine(int quantity){
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.stato = StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE;
    }

    public InfoOrdine() {
    }

    // getter and setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[quantity:'" + quantity + '\'' +
                ", stato:'" + stato + '\'' + "]";
    }
    public enum StatoOrdine {
        DA_PREPARARE,
        IN_PREPARAZIONE,
        COMPLETATO;
    }
}
```

Please, i'm stuck in this problem and i don't know how to resolve. I'm sorry for this very long question.

I expect to save tha table indo_ordine with tha right value of column id_piatto and id_ordinazione.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).